# "Incomplete type is not allowed" error when compiling the C++ code

Tags: c++

I was trying to make `GradeBook` class which represents grade book for a course. Which has the private member variable which stores the name of the course. Class sets the member and gets the course name and also displays welcome message. As I'm beginner to `C++`, I've got the following error:

```
Incomplete type is not allowed
```

- Here is the source code that I was working on:

  ```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<string>
  using namespace std;
  class GradeBook; // GradeBook class definition
  {
  public:
     // constructor initializes courseName
    GradeBook(string name)
    {
        setCourseName(name);
    }
    void setCourseName(string name)
    {
        courseName = name;
    }
    string getCourseName()
    {
        return courseName;
    }
    void displayMessage()
    {
        cout << "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName() << "!" << endl;
    }
  private:
    string courseName;
  };

  int main()
  {

    GradeBook gradeBook1("CS101 Introduction to C++ Programming");
    GradeBook gradeBook2("Visual C++ introduction");

    cout << "gradeBook1 created for course: " << gradeBook1.getCourseName()
        << "\ngradeBook2 created for course: " << gradeBook2.getCourseName()
        << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  ```
- Expected outcome:

  ```
  gradeBook1 created for course: CS101 Introduction to C++ Programming
  gradeBook2 created for course: Visual C++ introduction
  ```

Comment: The error is probably caused by a simple typo: `class GradeBook;`. The succeeding `;` makes the "incomplete" type but is wrong here. Please, remove it.

Comment: Read the error list from the beginning, not the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `;` after `class Gradebook` and everything should be fine.